# start opened file from sublimetext in associated program

Tags: sublimetext2

i usually edit files in sublime text 2 that can also be edited and compiled with another program. As i have them already opened in sublimetext i do the following:

1. right click and choose "copy file path" (to clipboard)
2. Win+R to open windows run dialog
3. CTRL+V to paste the file path
4. hit enter to open the file with the associated program

i wonder some shortcut can be configured so it automatically starts the opened file with its associate program

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.  I was in a very similar situation using Sublime as my editor of choice over the default SAS program editor.  I was able to use the `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch` module to connect to SAS via OLE and pass text from Sublime directly to SAS using Sublime's build system to call my plugin.  Making the connection was the easy part, it was the other processing that I had to do which was the time consuming part, but since you want to pass just a file name or the entire contents of your file, this should be a fairly straightforward plugin.  Since I do not know what program you wish to open, here is the code that makes my implementation work.  Maybe you caan glean something out of this.

```
def send_to_sas_via_ole(selected_code):

    from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch
    sasinstance = Dispatch("SAS.Application")

    # submit the lines to sas
    for selection in selected_code:
        # for some reason cannot send as one big line to SAS, so split into
        # multipe lines and send line by line
        for line in selection.splitlines():
            sasinstance.Submit(line)
```

and then the call in the run method of my plugin class:

```
class RunSasMakoCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

def run(self, edit):

    try:
        send_to_sas_via_ole(selected_code)
    except Exception as e: 
        print "\n".join(selected_code)
        print "Couldn't connect to SAS OLE"
        print e
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 'regedit.exe';
2. Navigate to

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text.exe\shell\open\command
   ```
3. correct the path. Exit 'regedit.exe'
4. (optional) restart 'explorer.exe' or reboot your PC.

enjoy :p;

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file, press "Properties". You will see `Opens with SomeProgram` and then a change button. Click on the change button, and then look through the list for Sublime Text, if you can't find it, you can choose an application using the file explorer, from there you can navigate to `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2` and choose sublime_text.exe